is there a way to exclude certain biologically irrelevant pairwise comparisons when running a sma with the SMATR package?
I am mainly interested in whether there are any differences in the scaling relationship of the antennal lobe (one part of the insect brain) volume between wild-caught and insectary-reared individuals of the same species. My data has a column wild.insectary for whether the individuals are wild-caught or insectary-reared, and a column for species (of which there are 5).
I used the sma function in the SMATR package to check whether the slopes of the regression lines differ, and if not then whether there is an elevational shift or major-axis shift. However, I get an overall significant difference in slope (see output) but no significant pairwise comparisons (see table). We think that this might be because the p-values are being heavily adjusted for the number of comparisons (of which I am not interested in and are not biologically relevant, e.g the wild of species 1 vs the insectary of species 2).
Indeed when I set the option to not adjust the p-values, I get significant pairwise comparisons. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to cancel out all the comparisons that I am not interested in so the p-values can be less heavily penalized and I would get more accurate results?
In theory, I could not adjust the p-values when running sma and then pick the comparisons I am interested in and then adjust it subsequently with p-adjust, but I thought that might affect the results of comparing lines among groups (see output) in sma.
Code
Since sma cannot take more than 1 group as a parameter, I combined wild.insectary & species with an interaction term to form a new group.
data$int<-interaction(data$wild.insectary,data$species)

#running the sma (rCBR.log is a variable that is used as an allometric control)
a2<- sma(AL.log~rCBR.log*int, robust=F, data=data, multcomp = T ,multcompmethod = "adjust")

gives
Call: sma(formula = AL.log ~ rCBR.log * int, data = data, multcomp = T, robust = F) 

Fit using Standardized Major Axis 

------------------------------------------------------------
Results of comparing lines among groups.

H0 : slopes are equal.
Likelihood ratio statistic : 19.09 with 9 degrees of freedom
P-value : 0.024428 


and

Hcyd, Hism, Hhel etc. are the different species. As you can see from the table, there are no significant pairwise comparisons.

Hi and welcome! Where do I find the reproducible programming question? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
